# Django Rest Framework APITestCase does not use JSON datatypes for all fields

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

Using DRF's APITestCase, I expect the results of an API test to be serialized to JSON datatypes. An object with a property `size = decimal.Decimal('20.0')` is correctly sent through the API endpoint as `size: 20.0` (with the `COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING` parameter set to `True`).

However, when testing the endpoint with the APITestCase, the original data type is kept. `APIClient.get(url).response.data.get("size").__class__` = decimal.Decimal

The same happens with other complex types.

Why is this? And can it be changed to seeing what the API client would receive?

Comment: can you add the minimal test case and a related code snippet that can be used to reproduce the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need to call the **`.json()`** method of the response

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase


class DRFTest(APITestCase):
    def test_decimal(self):
        res = self.client.get("some/-url")
        self.assertEqual(
            res.json()["size"],
            20.0
        )
```